# Is it possible to prevent the browser from parsing certain elements?

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, html-table

Consider the following markup:

```
<div hidden id="table-template">
<table>
<tbody>
  <slot></slot>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div hidden id="table-row-template">
<tr>
  <td>
    Some Content
  </td>
</tr>
</div>
```

I would like to use 'table-template' and 'table-row-template' as re-usable components in my script.
(clone them and append them on demand)
but as the page loads the browser parses the markup and mutates it (taking 'slot' element and insert it before the 'table' element, and stripping 'td' and 'tr' tags).

This is reasonable (not valid HTML of course), but is there any way I can prevent the browser from parsing those elements?

So far I have tried:
using hidden elements,
wrapping with 'pre'/'code' tags,
but none seem to work.

Comment: Take a look at HTML [templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template).

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `<script type="text/template"></script>`

```
<script id="mytemplate" type="text/template">
  ...your table's html...
</script>
```

Then:

```
<script>
  alert($('#mytemplate').html());
</script>
```

Many libraries use this method, `handlebar.js` for example.

The `<template>` element may gain compatibility with more browser versions: http://caniuse.com/#feat=template

Answer (score 1):

Use a fictional tag that the browser wouldn't recognise. You can still target it with Javascript and read it's text content but the browser won't parse it.

Say `<template id="the-template">Foo bar</template>`.

But really the best way to re-use html snippets it to create them in Javascript without polluting the DOM.

e.g

```
var elToReuse = document.createElement('div').innerHTML('<h1>Lets have title here</h1>');
// Let's do some things to the elToReuse
var anotherVersion = elToReuse.querySelector('h1').innerText('My another title');

// Now it's the time to append to the DOM
document.body.appendChild(anotherVersion);
```

Comment: the 'template' tag, fixes the issue on the 'table-row-template', but the browser (chrome-58) still alters the 'table-template', (taking the 'slot' element from inside the table and append it to the template) have a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/gjgsyL5v/1/

Comment: 'But really the best way to re-use html snippets it to create them in Javascript without polluting the DOM' - I do not agree with this assumption. The process of injecting html-snippets into the DOM is much more expensive then cloning existing DOM elements.

Comment: sure... Check this one: https://jsperf.com/clonenode-vs-createelement-performance/32

Answer (score 0):

So I have researched a bit about my problem, and this is what i figured out -
the 'tbody' element accpets only 'tr' elements as children.
so browsers will 'fix' the markup while parsing it one way or the other.
using template tags as vassiliskrikonis suggested will not work for the 'table-template' but will fix the 'table-row-template' issue, 
using script tag as @Mihaly_KR suggested will work for both, but when accessing the template you will get a plain string to work with (injecting this string into the DOM will make the browser parse it and 'fix' it once again...)

The workaround I have found is to use other tag as a placeholder for my content.
one way is using a comment e.g. 
but accessing this comment element requires a use of treeWalker or nodeIterator (which are much less performant then querySelector or getElementsByTagName)
other way is using a script tag as a placeholder.
browsers will not change the markup, and it can be accessed later using querySelector or getElementsByTagName.

so my refactored code looks like this:

```
<template id="table-template">
<table>
<tbody>
  <script type="slot"></script>
</tbody>
</table>
</template>
<template id="table-row-template">
<tr>
  <td>
    Some Content
  </td>
</tr>
</template>
```